# ios offering protected limited access to Wikipedia

Tags: ios, wikipedia

My IOS app offers access to specific Wikipedia URLs using webviews.  Apple want me to classify the app for people aged 17+, since 
it offers unprotected access to the web and to Wikipedia.
How can I best restrict users to specific Wikipedia URLs?  In order to get around this rather eccentric requirement of the Apple Store?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do content filtering on Wikipedia. It's an encyclopedia, it doesn't require any filtering. Tell Apple to enter the 20th century, if not the 21st.

Useful reference: http://www.ifla.org/publications/node/224?og=30